# Power Query won't read from .xls files

Tags: powerquery

I am using Office 2010. I have a query that combines data from several excel files in a folder. ".xlsx" files load fine, but when a ".xls" file exists in the folder, the query will not run (Gives error message: "Data could not be retrieved from database". In the query editor, when I click on the row for the file with an error, I see the message here: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmh0E.png) ). Resaving the files to ".xlsx" works, but I'd rather be able to use them as-is.

I have installed the MS Access Database Engine here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 but it doesn't seem to help.

Any other ideas? Thanks!
Edit: Added the two queries. First is the query applied to each file, second is the query that combines them.

Query "Transform Sample File from Supplier CMRTs":

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(#"Sample File Parameter1", null, true),
    #"Smelter List_Sheet" = Source{[Item="Smelter List",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Smelter List_Sheet",3),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"Smelter Identification Number Input Column", "Metal (*)", "Smelter Look-up (*)", "Comments"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each [#"Metal (*)"] <> null and [#"Metal (*)"] <> "")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Query "Supplier CMRTs":

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("O:\Supplier CMRTs"),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Transform File from Supplier CMRTs", each #"Transform File from Supplier CMRTs"([Content])),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Invoke Custom Function1", each [Extension] <> ".txt"),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File from Supplier CMRTs"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File from Supplier CMRTs", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File from Supplier CMRTs"(#"Sample File")))
in
    #"Expanded Table Column1"
```

Comment: What does your query look like? You can see this by going to the Advanced Editor.

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT added to my post.

Comment: If you make a new query and call Excel.Workbook with a path to an .xls file, what values show up in the Item and Kind columns (in that step, not the post-navigation steps)? The error you are seeing occurs when Power Query can't find the row with the cell values specified. In this case, it can't find a row with Kind=Sheet and Item=Smelter List.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I combine binaries, if I select the *Sample Binary Parameter* instead of a *Sheet*, and work my way from there, it will not balk at xls vs xlsx files. But before I could even get to the point where I could combine binaries for the folder, I had to filter only to xlsx files. Therefore, after I successfully combine the binaries, I have to go back to the *Applied Steps* and remove the one where I filtered only to xlsx files.

Here are some step-by-step with screen clips:

I started with 4 Excel Sheets in one Folder, called *New Folder*:

[image]

*Here's what their data looks like:*

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

Establish a new source from folder. ***Do not click Combine & Edit.*** Click the Edit button:

[image]

Filter the *Extension* column to only xlsx files:

[image]

Right-click on the column name for the *Content* column and then click *Remove Other Columns*, so you'll only have a *Content* column:

[image]

Click [image] to combine the binaries. Then click the *folder level Sample Binary Parameter* and click OK:

[image]

Go to your *Applied Steps* and remove the *Filtered Rows* step, where you filtered to only xlsx files: Change...

[image] to... [image]

Also remove the *Changed Type* step from the *Applied Steps*, because it now won't work and isn't needed.

Now your query should work with **both** your xlsx *and* xls files.

For completeness, here's what I have at this step (all 4 of my files each have only one sheet, called *Sheet1* in each, which is why you see 4 *Sheet1* names):

[image]

Anyhow, the names dont matter for me, so I delete the *Name* column and expand the *Data* column to get:

[image]

You should recognize the data as the data from all 4 sheets above.